# How can i use this js function for document.querySelectorAll for each same Class Element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is an animation effect that run after checkbox is active. It works okay but this is working for only one element with `class="text"`. But I want to use it for each element that has `class="text"`.

How can I do that, I tried [this method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbytagname3), but did not get success.

My Whole Code is Here:

```js
function myTYPINGFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.text');

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
      return `<span class="word">` +
        m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
        `</span>`;
    });

    var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.text .letter'));

    anime.timeline({
        loop: true,
      })
      .add({
        targets: targets,
        scale: [3, 1],
        scaleY: [1.5, 1],
        opacity: [0, 1],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 400,
        delay: (el, i) => 60 * i
      }).add({
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 50000,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        delay: 800
      })
    $(".text").removeClass('zoomIn2');

  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
    }, 550);


    var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.text .letter'));

    anime.timeline({
        loop: false,
      })
      .add({
        targets: targets.reverse(),
        scale: [1, 2],
        scaleY: [1, 1.5],
        opacity: [1, 0],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 30,
        delay: (el, i) => 25 * i
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".text").addClass('zoomIn2');
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

```css
.word {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

input.largerCheckbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.zoomIn2 {
  animation: zoomIn2 1000ms both
}

@keyframes zoomIn2 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheck" style="color:red; font-size:20px;"><b>Typing.Eff:</b></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="largerCheckbox" onclick="myTYPINGFunction()">

<h1 class="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
<h1 class="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
```

I want same effect as first `h1 class="text"` on all elements with `class="text"`

Even though if need to change class name, it does not matter like

```
<h1 class="text_1">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
<h1 class="text_2">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get all elements with class `text`, and iterate over those elements. You can do it by method `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

`querySelector` always will return you only first matched element.

Then you can use forEach method to iterate over each element with class text. Your animation will be added to every element.

Here is part of code you need to change:

```js
 var textWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
      
textWrappers.forEach( textWrapper => {
```

Also you need to change this line:

```js
var targets = Array.from(textWrapper.querySelectorAll('.letter'));
```

Here is working code:

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>
    .word {border: 1px solid red;}
    .letter {border: 1px solid lightblue;}
        input.largerCheckbox { 
                width: 20px; 
                height: 20px; 
            } 

    .zoomIn2 {
        animation: zoomIn2 1000ms both
    }
    @keyframes zoomIn2 {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    </style>

    <label for="myCheck" style="color:red; font-size:20px;"><b>Typing.Eff:</b></label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="largerCheckbox" onclick="myTYPINGFunction()">

    <h1 class="text" >Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
    <h1 class="text" >Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>

    <script>
    function myTYPINGFunction() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      var textWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
      
textWrappers.forEach( textWrapper => {
      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
      return `<span class="word">` +
        m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
        `</span>`;
    });

    var targets = Array.from(textWrapper.querySelectorAll('.letter'));

    anime.timeline({
      loop: true,
    })
      .add({
        targets: targets,
        scale: [3,1],
        scaleY: [1.5,1],
        opacity: [0,1],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 400,
        delay: (el, i) => 60*i
        }).add({
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 50000,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        delay: 800
      })
      $(".text").removeClass('zoomIn2');
      
      } else {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
         textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
         }, 550);
         
         
         var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.text .letter'));

    anime.timeline({
      loop: false,
    })
    .add({
        targets: targets.reverse(),
        scale: [1,2],
        scaleY: [1,1.5],
        opacity: [1,0],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 30,
        delay: (el, i) => 25*i
      }); 
      setTimeout(function(){ 
      $(".text").addClass('zoomIn2');
      }, 500);
      }
       })
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: But it is not working together, the first is working complete and then second is start, how can i run animation together with all element plz plz

Comment: even though need to change class name, its not matter like <h1 class="text_1">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>
<h1 class="text_2">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1>

Comment: I've edited my code snippet. You need to change this line: `var targets = Array.from(textWrapper.querySelectorAll('.letter'));`

Comment: its nice But the first one reverse animation is not working

Comment: means the reverse animation is working on only Last element plz make it solved, try to add <h1 class="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</h1> one more element and see